# Python Selenuim - InvalidArgumentExpression: unexpected end of hex escape

Tags: python, selenium

I keep getting this error each time I try to use `driver.page_source`:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***\grapusers.py", line 111, in <module>
    getUsers(args.groupName,wait,driver)
  File "***\grapusers.py", line 22, in getUsers
    UsersCount = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 679, in page_source
    return self.execute(Command.GET_PAGE_SOURCE)['value']
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: unexpected end of hex escape at line 1 column 76022
```

I tried to convert `driver.page_source` to `utf-8` but didn't work with me.
Any ideas on fix?

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: i'm posting the answer @user3415910

Comment: i'm not sure but as i remember it bc of the page was in arabic language.. I cannot remember what was the right answer but try this out. get the page in string utf-8 somehow to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when using `WebElement.get_attribute("outerHTML")`.
I solved it by first escaping the HTML in JavaScript, and then unescaping in Python. Extended Unicode code points needed to be handled manually, with invalid surrogates replaced with something valid. Here's the helper I created:

```py
from urllib.parse import unquote

from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement


def get_outer_html(element: WebElement) -> str:
    """Get the element's outer HTML, handling Unicode extended code points correctly.

    :param element: The element.
    :return: The element's outer HTML.

    """
    outer_html_escaped = element.parent.execute_script(
        r"""
        var S = arguments[0].outerHTML;
        var length = S.length;
        var REPLACEMENT_CHARACTER = '\uFFFD';
        var result = Array(length);
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          var charCode = S.charCodeAt(i);
          // single UTF-16 code unit
          if ((charCode & 0xF800) != 0xD800) result[i] = S.charAt(i);
          // unpaired surrogate
          else if (
            charCode >= 0xDC00
            || i + 1 >= length
            || (S.charCodeAt(i + 1) & 0xFC00) != 0xDC00
          ) result[i] = REPLACEMENT_CHARACTER;
          // surrogate pair
          else {
            result[i] = S.charAt(i);
            result[++i] = S.charAt(i);
          }
        }
        return encodeURI(result.join(''));
        """,
        element,
    )
    return unquote(outer_html_escaped)
```